# Proof Verification- $f$ is positive on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Let $f$ be twice differentiable such that $f(0)=0,\ f'(0)>0$ and
>   $f''\geq f$. Prove $f>0$ on $(0,\infty)$

My attempt- Expanding $f$'s taylor polynomial we get
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f'(0)x+R_1(x)}{x}=f'(0)+\frac{R_1(x)}{x}$$
Because $R_1(x)/x\rightarrow0$ then theres a neighborhood $(0,\delta)$ in which $ \left |\frac{R_1(x)}{x}  \right |<\frac{|f'(0)|}{2}$ and hence $f$ is positive.

Now we assume there's a point $x_0>\delta$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ (wlog we take the "first one" after $\delta$). $f$ has a maxima on $[0,x_0]$ achieved at $x_{\max}$. We get $f(x_{\max})>0>f''(x_\max)$ by contradiction.

Is my proof correct? and if so, would you change anything about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nitpicking: "We get $f(x_\text{max})>0\geq f″(x_\text{max})$, which is a contradiction." Perfect otherwise. Also, since you explained quite clearly why $f$ has to be positive in a neighbourhood of $0$, for consistency perhaps you should use Taylor again to explain why $0\geq f″(x_\text{max})$

Comment: I wrongly answered your question (now deleted the answer). You may just note that $f'(0)>0$ and this means by definition of derivative itself that $f(x)>f(0)=0$ to the right of $0$.

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that I wasn't wrong! Anyhow, do you guys have any alternative elegant solutions that I could learn from?

Comment: Alternative solution: You can use the derivative of $\exp(-x)(f^{\prime}+f)$ to show that $f^{\prime}+f$ is $>0$ for $x>0$. Then the fact that the derivative of $\exp(x)f$ is $\exp(x)(f^{\prime}+f)$ to finish.